# How to check the Encoding scheme on the API response

Tags: python, json, encryption, base64, decode

I am getting the API response from the URL as follows :

I am not sure what encoding scheme is used. I am not sure how to check this and decode the string. I tried base64 decode and its not the one.

To give you a background : 
I used Packet Capture App to capture the request sent by the APP and the response. So there was no API documentation.

> 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\u003d

Any help in this regard would be really helpful

Comment: It definitely looks like Base64, except for the Unicode escape at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is Base64, the error is the last character "\u003d" which is a UTF-16 "=", replace "\u003d"' with "=" and it decodes properly to binary. Trailing Base64 encoded "="characters are padding.

Since it decode as Base64 and the trailing "=" character it sure seems to be Base64 encoded data.

The Base64 decoded binary in a hex representation is:
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

To me that looks like random data which is what encrypted data looks like, if so without the decryption key you will not be able to further decrypt it. It is 512 bytes in length which is multiple of common encryption block sizes.